# python+MySQLdb, simple select is too slow compared to flat file access

Tags: python, performance, optimization, mysql-python

- I have one simple table with 80 000 rows.
- I'm trying to select and save all rows to python list as fast as possible.
- It's taking around 4 - 10 seconds.

In contrast If I dump exact same table into csv file and process it with this code

```
f = open('list.csv','rb')
lines = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()
print len(lines)
```

**It's taking only 0.08 - 0.3 second**

---

I tried MySQLdb and mysql.connector   using fetchall() or fetchone()

```
import time
start = time.time()
import MySQLdb as mdb
con = mdb.connect('127.0.0.1', 'login', 'p', 'db');

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    print len(rows)
print 'MySQLdb %s' % (time.time()-start)
```

**Took 3.7 - 8 seconds with high CPU load**

Is it possible to achieve same speed like with that csv file?

**EDIT**
My MySQL server seems to be ok.
In mysql console:

```
SELECT * from TABLE;
....
80789 rows in set (0.21 sec)
```

Comment: That seems excessive for a simple select. You are 100% sure it's an actual table and not a view?

Comment: The problem is about your database server's configuration or database design and has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: Subtract the time it takes to run the query from the command line from your excecution time. Then compare to the csv file.

Comment: "I'm trying to select and save all rows to python list as fast as possible." ... Uh ... *Why?*

Comment: I tried to run the query in mysql console: 80789 rows in set (0.21 sec)

Comment: try pyodbc and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: To get a fair comparison, you may want to move `start = time.time()` below the `mdb.connect` call. But >4 seconds sounds way too much, Such a large overhead in the Python client surprises me. Please note that there are multiple client libraries on https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=mysql&submit=search , e.g. I'd try cymysql.

Comment: Hi, did you find any answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

The entire query result will be restored in client side as a list when `cur.execute(...)` is done. Check self._rows attribute in MySQLdb/cursor.py for this.

That is to say, time cost differs in reading file content and fetching query results from a MySQL database. As we all, a built-in function is always faster than a 3PP function. So I don't think there is a way to make `cursor.execute()` same speed as `open()`.

As for why `open()` is faster, I suggest you look into Python source code. Here is the [link](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3).

Hope it helps.